How can I tell whether or not user has the new MS Office visual style?
I make a c# add-in for an MS Office desktop app. It uses WPF for front end UI. I want the background of the forms in the add-in to match the Office app colors.
Microsoft recently launched a brand-new visual style for office. I want to be able to check programmatically if the user has the 'visual refresh' or not in order to correctly style my forms.
I've tried just checking the registry (as stated from this article), but that doesn't always work. Sometimes a user has the 'visual refresh' even without those registry keys being present. I need a check that is more reliable if it exists.
I also can't just check if the user is Windows 11 vs Windows 10, because Windows 10 users can also get the visual refresh, and I've seen some Windows 11 users that still have the old styles.

"and I've seen some Windows 11 users that still have the old styles." - FWIW, this is accomplished by installing the 2109 build of Office 365 and then using Group Policy to disable all Office automatic updates.

To solve this, you'll need to do something like this - while also looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\UI Theme
